# How to update elastic search in spring boot without changing the elastic server

Tags: java, elasticsearch, pom.xml

I am using elastic search server 7.17.0 in my java project and i am using maven version for elastic as 7.17.0 but i found some security vulnerability in this version, so i want to update the maven version to 7.17.1 or higher but i can't upgrade elastic server. So is there a way to achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can always upgrade your client without upgrading the server so long as both are compatible with each other.

Looks like 7.17.0 -> 7.17.1 is a patch upgrade, it should not have any breaking changes.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-compatibility.html)

> The 7.0 client is able to communicate with any 7.x Elasticsearch node,
> while the 7.1 client is for sure able to communicate with 7.1, 7.2 and
> any later 7.x version, but there may be incompatibility issues when
> communicating with a previous Elasticsearch node version, for instance
> between 7.1 and 7.0, in case the 7.1 client supports new request body
> fields for some APIs that are not known by the 7.0 node(s).